# Scrape url link in table by BS4

Tags: beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape the hyperlinks in the tag (a herf) of the table. However, it doesn't work.  Can you help to improve this code?

[image: img_table]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
  
dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1,11):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/racing/RaceCard.aspx?RaceDate=2021/02/06&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo='+str(i)+'')
    res = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.quit()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
    h_table = soup.find('table', {'class':'table_bd f_tac f_fs13'})
   

    def tableDataText(h_table):       
        rows = []
        trs = h_table.find_all('tr')
        headerow = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in trs[0].find_all('th')] # header row
        if headerow: # if there is a header row include first
            rows.append(headerow)
            trs = trs[1:]
        for tr in trs: # for every table row
            rows.append([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all('td')]) # data row    
        return rows
    result_table = tableDataText(h_table)
    df = pd.DataFrame(result_table[1:], columns=result_table[0])
    dfs = pd.concat([dfs, df], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question and the expected result is not that clear and should be improved - If just wanna grab all the urls from the href you can go with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
  
linkList = []
for i in range(1,11):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/racing/RaceCard.aspx?RaceDate=2021/02/06&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo='+str(i)+'')
    time.sleep(6)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    driver.quit()
    
    for a in soup.select('table#racecardlist table a'):
        linkList.append('https://racing.hkjc.com'+a['href'])
        
linkList
```